# Thin Server - Virtual Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, thin

In production, we deploy our application to a virtual path:

```
https://hostname/my-virtual-path/
```

So the route '/users/' in development is actually accessed on `https://hostname/my-virtual-path/` in production.

This means that routes are different between development (/users/) and production (/my-virtual-path/users/).  Normally this is handled by setting the environment variable RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT or config.action_controller.relative_url_root so the paths Rails generates with its URL helpers is adjusted depending on the setting of these variables.  Unfortunately, our assets are going to be pre-compiled BEFORE we know what this setting will be.

Is there a way to run a Rails server in development mode, using thin, that will serve files to a virtual path?  For example, I want to type:

```
thin start --ssl -p 3000 --path whatever-i-want
```

and be able to access the root URL at `https://localhost:3000/whatever-i-want` in order to test my application.

Comment: AFAIK, for that you'd need to configure Rails app, not Thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’re after the `--prefix` option. From the output to `thin -h`:

```
--prefix PATH                Mount the app under PATH (start with /)
```

In your case something like this:

```
thin start --ssl -p 3000 --prefix /whatever-i-want
```

(Note you need to start the prefix with `/`.)